# How to mount Samba / SMB shares under macOS from a terminal?

Tags: macos, shell, smb

I need to be able mount Samba (SMB) shares from a macOS terminal. How can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just like you would do in any common *nix system, you first have to create a directory which will serve as the mount point:

```
mkdir -p ~/some/folder
```

Then mount the SMB share:

```
mount_smbfs //host/share ~/some/folder
```

If your server requires a username, password, and a domain:

```
mount_smbfs //domain;user:password@host/share ~/some/folder
```

Of course you can also leave out the password, and `mount_smbfs` will prompt you for it:

```
$ mount_smbfs //user@host/share ~/some/folder
Password for host: …
```

Check out [`man mount`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/mount.8.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/8/mount) for a list of common options to pass to the `-o` switch. For storing authentication, see [`nsmb.conf`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/nsmb.conf.5.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/5/nsmb.conf).

To unmount, just call:

```
umount ~/some/folder
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's really helpfull. I'm just new in MAC OSX and Cocoa. What I need is to create some user, and enable SMB sharing on that user, so it will be accessible only for that user (make that user hide if possible) Is it possible to do?

Comment: I tried but it won't work for me. I  need to mount SMB for user, like you can do it from System Preferences, with choosing users.

Comment: @User1234 What do you mean? Which "SMB for user"? What does "mount SMB for user" mean, exactly? From System Preferences, you can *enable* a SMB share, which will be available to the network, not *mount* it.

Comment: I will try to explain , what I want. I need help really ASAP. And I'm new in all this bash commands. I want to create user from APP (hidden if possible ) and after share folders (already know how to do it from terminal) . After I want to enable SMB sharing on that user account. So server, can access my shared folders, with that user, that I created. Help is really appreciated Thanks

Comment: @User1234 Then this is the wrong question – here, I explained you how to *connect* to a given share, not how to *enable* it. Finally you explained your real situation to me, so thank you for that. You already asked that question here: [How to enable User Account SMB sharing from terminal on MAC OSX?](http://superuser.com/questions/344450/how-to-enable-user-account-smb-sharing-from-terminal-on-mac-osx)

Comment: What you mean with saying connect share? Do you have any idea how can I do that? I need ASAP.

Comment: I could only get it to work using parentheses: `mount -t smbfs //"domain;user"@host/share`. I could not specify the password no matter what though. I tried `//"domain;user:pass"@host/share` and `//"domain;user":pass@host/share` and `//"domain;user":"pass"@host/share` but they were all met with `mount_smbfs: server connection failed: No route to host` - any ideas?

Comment: @OhadSchneider The syntax is correct. Note that the parentheses will get stripped by the shell before passing the argument to the `mount_smbfs` command, so they are only needed if the domain, username, or password contain special characters that would otherwise be interpreted by the shell (like `*`) or whitespace. The `no route to host` error stems from something else – it means your client cannot reach the IP address or domain of the server you specified. Are you sure it's routable from your machine?

Comment: Like I said, when I omit the password I can connect to the server (after providing the password when prompted), so it's not really a routing issue. As for the parentheses, I am not sure why (I am aware of globbing and shell expansion) but they are definitely needed for my completely alphanumeric domain and user. Maybe it's the semi-colon tripping it?

Comment: @OhadSchneider I see. Could you provide an example command that you're using? Is the password alphanumeric, too, or does it contain any special characters? Could be that it simply mistakes it for the host and finds it non-routable.

Comment: The only non-alphanumeric character in the password is `#` and as far as I know that should not cause trouble. In addition, two of the variations I tried had the password in quotes. A full example command that is very similar to the actual one I'm using (which I can't share verbatim for obvious reasons): `mount -t smbfs //"DOMAIN;myuser01:pa##word"@host/share`. I also tried `mount -t smbfs //"DOMAIN;myuser01":"pa##word"@host/share`. I guess I could always pipe the password using `echo` but it's a bit less elegant (having to pipe the newline character).

Comment: @OhadSchneider There's someone describing the same issue on Stack Overflow in a [now-deleted, abandoned question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28727132/unable-to-escape-a-pound-hash-in-mount-smbfs). If it cannot be escaped with quotes or backslashes, it must be some bug in the program—I'd then probably resort to `echo`ing it in.

Comment: Nice find! Looks like you're right...

Comment: What is the password is empty? My password was empty (in Windows, just press Enter to login), but pressing Enter when being prompted from OSX Terminal throws an authentication error.

Comment: @hyiltiz Couldn't you just `//user@host` without a password? But to be honest, I'm not a Windows expert, hence cannot answer that particular question.

Comment: Nope, that prompts for a password, and anything sensible for the password doesn't work. Using //user:@HOST/path doesn't work either. Couldn't find anything in anywhere about this that works.

Comment: Maybe that worked in 2011, but it doesn't with Sierra 10.12. Try it. (I tried various combinations with and without sudo, and with and without creating the directory first).

Comment: @mivk It still works under 10.13.1. If you have a more specific problem, please create a new question.